# Fragment translation and phone orientation bug

Tags: java, android

Phone's orientation and fragment translation bug.

I have an activity and some fragments. The first fragment comes right away over the activity with a logo and after 3 seconds the second fragment translates over. The problem is if I change the orientation of the phone, the 1st fragment reappears with the same delay and same behavior as I start the app.

MainActivity:

```
package com.mainpackage.pinbook;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.mainpackage.pinbook.com.autentification.LoginFragment;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container , new MainScreen());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

MainScreen:

```
package com.mainpackage.pinbook;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.mainpackage.pinbook.com.autentification.*;

public class MainScreen extends Fragment{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_screen , container , false);
}

private TextView entry_text;
public static final String TAG = MainScreen.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            slide();
        }
    }, 3000);

}

private void slide(){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(0,R.anim.slide_in_left);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container , new LoginFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
}
```

The second fragment can be blank.

What I want is simply to remain on the current fragment when I change the phone's orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the device rotates `onCreate()` gets called again.
Wrap your fragment transaction in `onCreate()` like so:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container , new MainScreen());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

This will prevent the first fragment from being put back on top when you rotate.

Comment: Thank god! I tried basically everything! Enjoy your like mate! :)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Yeye! Sorry! There you go! :)

Comment: Can you also vote my question? I need to get rid of a ban. Thank you!